# How to install the master version of MongoDB River Plugin for ElasticSearch

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch

I have installed *MongoDB* (2.6.1) and *ElasticSearch* (1.2.0) with the plugin *mapper-attachments* without any problems. When I want to install the master version of the plugin [MongoDB River Plugin for ElasticSearch](https://github.com/richardwilly98/elasticsearch-river-mongodb#mongodb-river-plugin-for-elasticsearch) I am getting an error informing me that the plugin does not contain binary but source. When I install an older version e.g. 2.0.0. the installation goes fine (but I got some Java problems, which I hope to have been fixed in the master version).

The correct error I am getting is:

*Message:
   Error while installing plugin, reason: IllegalArgumentException: Plugin installation assumed to be site plugin, but contains source code, aborting installation.*

Anyone can give some tips on how to install the master version of MongoDB River Plugin for ElasticSearch?

Comment: From Git checkout? **Don't** unless you really know what you are letting yourself in for. Since you have problems I guess you don't. Always switch your local copy from a repository to a released "tag" or "branch" ( probably tag ) before you build. Bleeding edge commits on "master" are generally destined to break.

Comment: What do you advice. With version 2.0.0 of the plugin installed I am getting an error when starting elasticsearch (1.2.0). The error I am getting in this case is {1.2.0}: Initialization Failed ...
- ExecutionError[java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/elasticsearch/rest/XContentRestResponse]
        NoClassDefFoundError[org/elasticsearch/rest/XContentRestResponse]
                ClassNotFoundException[org.elasticsearch.rest.XContentRestResponse]
org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionError: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/elasticsearch/rest/XContentRestResponse

Comment: The mongodb river plugin does not support ES 1.2 yet. Downgrade ES to 1.1.1.

Comment: Thanks @Dema I did, now I just got a load of other problems. Do you know Elastic Search well and are you willing to help me out via Skype to tackle the problems I have? There are 3 issues that are stopping me from wrapping up my "project".